# what is difference between "play", "act" and "playact", and how they are used

Tags: word-usage

so first of all, playact has a definition of "Act in a play", according to oxford dictionary,

and play is "Behave as though one were (a specified type of person)",

and as for act, it is "Behave so as to appear to be; pretend to be"

so my question is, is it "play dumb" or "act dumb" and what is the difference between these two. what about "playact"? how and when it is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer by @James K is correct as fr as it goes, but it does not directly deal with "play dumb" or "act dumb".

> He is playing dumb so that I would bring up his failure.

This means that the person is **pretending** to be unaware or ignorant. It implies that this is a deliberate, deceptive maneuver. The person is not "dumb" (here used to mean "stupid" or "ignorant" )

> He is acting dumb by not allowing for the chance of something going wrong.

While "acting dumb" can be used for the same meaning as "playing dumb" it is mor often used, as here, to mean "behaving in an unwise or foolish manner". The implication is that this is not done on purpose.

In general "playing X" can be used to mean "pretending to be X", and "acting X" can be used to mean "behaving as if one were X". If the behavior is intentional, the meaning is pretty much the same. But "acting" covers a wider range, and is more often used when the behavior is not intentional. "playing" in this sense often carries a negative implication. "He is playing the boss" suggests that the person is trying to be in charge, but withot the right or perhaps the ability to do so correctly.

"Playing possum" is an idiom derived from this usage. It means pretending to be unconscious or dead in an attempt to avoid scrutiny or attack, from the reputed habit of the opossum to lie still as if dead to avoid predators.

There are of course many other usages of "play", for example:

- A position in a sport "He is playing shortstop."
- Performing a play: "The Royal Shakespeare Company is playing *Hamlet* this season."
- Something fun: "This job is so easy it is almost like play."
- Performing music: "The orchestra played Mozart."

and others.

By the way, using "play-acting" to mean "pretending" seems a bit old-fashioned to me -- i encounter it more in 19th or even 18th century writing than i do in anything current.

> That young lady isn't truly upset, she is only play-acting.

Note the tone of disapproval here, emphasized by "young lady" which is often used for a female child or young woman who is doing something that the speaker dislikes.

Answer (score 0):

The word "play" is used for example:

> I played [the part of] Ophelia in *Hamlet*.

It means to act in a particular (usually named) role.

"Act" can be used synomynously, but you can also say

> I have acted for many years (not played)

We can also say

> That footballer is just acting to get a penalty.

It means he is trying to deceive the referee.

In this last sense you might (rarely) hear "play-act" (normally hyphenated). It is pretty rare.

> The footballer was accused of play-acting, when the TV replay proved that no contact had taken place.

It might also be used of children's performances.

> Each Christmas the children dress-up and play-act one of their favourite films.

Here is means play (in the sense of childish fun) + act (perform)

Comment: is "playacting" a faster way of saying "acting in a play"?

Comment: @aggressionexp  not usually, one merely says 'acting' or 'playing' for that meaning. "play-acting" generally implies intentional deceptive behavior, and is a bit old-fashioned. See my answer.

Comment: @aggressionexp No.  Please re-read the answer where I give two examples of "play-act" and neither one means "acting in a play".